# getting ValueError: Cannot determine path without bucket name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

I'm running a PySpark job on a Dataproc cluster using Cloud Composer as the orchestration tool.

The job instantiates an object MyClass with a bucket attribute defined like so:

```
from google.cloud import storage
from .constants import GCS_BUCKET_NAME

class MyClass:
    bucket = storage.Client().bucket(GCS_BUCKET_NAME)

    def load_data(self, filepath: str, contents: str) -> None:
        blob = self.bucket.blob(filepath)
    blob.upload_from_string(contents)
```

and GCS_BUCKET_NAME is defined in a constants.py file as

`GCS_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv("DATA_BUCKET_NAME")`

The DATA_BUCKET_NAME environment variable is set using an initialization script:

```
#!bin/bash
DATA_BUCKET_NAME=$(/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/DATA_BUCKET_NAME)
echo "DATA_BUCKET_NAME=${DATA_BUCKET_NAME}" >> /etc/environment
```

When I connect with SSH into the cluster nodes of the Dataproc cluster, the environment variable is well defined.

But when the DAG runs in Cloud Composer, the job fails when the `load_data` function is called with the following error:
`ValueError: Cannot determine path without bucket name`

What I've tried so far but none of these seem to work:

- use the `storage.Client().get_bucket` method instead of `storage.Client().bucket`
- specify the project id: `storage.Client().get_bucket(GCS_BUCKET_NAME, PROJECT_ID)`
- allow more storage permissions to the dataproc service account

Thanks for your help!